# DOM (Javascript) show / hide divs not working

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I am unable to use AJAX (Server issues!) so am having to rely on DOM + javascript to show or hide two of the divs on my page.

A user clicks one of two radio buttons and depending on which is click the appropriate div is displayed.

For some reason the first div will load if the "EU" radio button is used but I cannot get the "international" radio button to work.  The second button calls the correct script, passes the variable and even hides the EU div, it just will not display the international one.

I'm at my wits end.  Can anybody help?

**Javascript:**

```
 function displayLocation(loc){
  alert(loc)
  document.getElementById(loc).style.display = "block"
  if (loc == "eu"){
  document.getElementById("international").style.display = "none"
  }else{
        document.getElementById("eu").style.display = "none"
  }
 }
```

**HTML Radio buttons**

```
 <input type="radio" name="loc" style="float:left;" onclick=displayLocation("eu")>
 <input type="radio" name="loc" style="float:left;" onclick=displayLocation("international")>
```

**Divs to hide/display as appropriate**

```
 <div id="eu" style="display:none;">European Union</div>
 <div id="international" style="display:none;">International</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2Y2nE/1/) I just made.

I was able to resolve the problem by placing the script *after* the HTML that calls it. There's a couple of stylistic things to tweak too (`onclick=displayLocation` should be in quotes) but other than that it should work fine for you.

Comment: i've made these changes  and no good

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap quotes around `displayLocation('xx')` in the onlick attribute as in: `'displayLocation("eu")'`

http://jsfiddle.net/rvtBp/

I would also suggest using event bindings instead of event attributes:

```
<input type="radio" name="loc" style="float:left;" data-lang="eu">
<input type="radio" name="loc" style="float:left;" data-lang="international">

Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('[name="loc"]'),
function (elem) {
    elem.addEventListener('change', function (e) {
        if (this.checked) {
            displayLocation(this.dataset.lang);
        }
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rvtBp/1/

Comment: tested - this isn't correct

Comment: @user2040862 can you be more specific please?

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="radio" name="loc" style="float:left;" onclick="displayLocation(\'' + eu + '\')">
```

onclick declaration should enclosed in quotes..**`onclick="displayLocation(\'' + eu + '\')"`**

i think it wont works.. `document.getElementById(loc).style.display = "block"`

```
 document.getElementById("+loc+").style.display = "block"
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to change onclick event to look like this

```
<input type="radio" name="loc" style="float:left;" onclick="displayLocation('eu')">

<input type="radio" name="loc" style="float:left;" onclick="displayLocation('international')">
```